# Grid function not working for labels with images in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am a beginner in Tkinter and having a tough time with the grid geometry manager. I was trying to move my label with an image to the 1st column of the window. But regardless of any number of columns I type, it always stays at the top-leftmost part of the window. Please advise me on this issue. Below is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk,Image

screen = tk.Tk()
screen.title("Login")
screen.geometry("2560x1600")
background = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("D:\StRaNgE\Background.jpg"))
background_label = tk.Label(screen, image = background)
background_label.place(x = 0, y = 0, relwidth = 1, relheight = 1)

logo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("D:\StRaNgE\logo2.jpg"))
lbl1 = tk.Label(screen, image=logo, relief = "solid", bd = 10, width = 1000, bg = "white")
lbl1.grid(row = 0, column = 1)        #This is not working

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: The row/column numbers are relative to other gridded items in the same container.  Since you only used `.grid()` with this one item, they're completely meaningless.

Comment: It is because there is nothing in column 0, so the width is zero.  However you can use `screen.columnconfigure(0, minsize=100)` to set the minimum width of first column.

Comment: @jasonharper Thank you very much. But pls put the answer in the answer section so I can upvote you

Comment: @acw1668 I got the perfect answer from you. I could have Accepted your answer only if you had put it in the answer section. Anyways, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is nothing in column 0, its width will be zero.  However you can use

```py
screen.columnconfigure(0, minsize=100) # change 100 to whatever you want
```

to set the minimum width of column 0.